# error using tcblisting inside longtable, no error inside tabular.

Tags: listings, longtable, tcolorbox, tcblisting

I was testing a nice solution provided in this answer [how-to-crop-background-color-in-listings-to-the-longest-line-in-the-code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312111/how-to-crop-background-color-in-listings-to-the-longest-line-in-the-code)

However, I happened to be using `longtable` and not the standard `tabular`. I did not think it will make a difference.

But for some reason, the code given generates an error when used inside `longtable`  Everything is exactly the same. Only difference is that instead of using `tabular`, I changed it to `longtable` and now a syntax error shows up.

Here is MWE (same code from the above link, I just changed `tabular` to `longtable`, since in my code, I am actually using `longtable` for everything)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{longtable}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.8\textwidth}|p{.2\textwidth}|}\hline
\begin{tcblisting}{colback=bg,size=minimal,hbox,
          listing only,listing options={language=Mathematica}}
f[x_] := Sin[x];
Plot[f[x],{x,-Pi,Pi}]
\end{tcblisting}
&
plot command
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Error is

```
pdflatex foo.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
.....
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(./foo.listing)
! Misplaced \noalign.
\pagebreak ->\noalign 
                      {\ifnum `}=0\fi \@testopt {\LT@no@pgbk -}4
l.16 \end{tcblisting}

?
```

change it back to `tabular` as in the original code, then there is no error!

filelist

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
listings.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 lstmisc.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2015/06/04 1.6 listings configuration
tcolorbox.sty    2015/11/27 version 3.80 text color boxes
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
verbatim.sty    2014/10/28 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
 environ.sty    2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

question is: How to make the above code work in `longtable` and not just in `tabular`?

Comment: I am not sure whether this can really work, using a verbatim content box inside a tabular cell

Comment: @ChristianHupfer but it works in `tabular`?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I am surprised about this

Comment: I think, this is a `longtable` speciality. David Carlisle will know some way (if there's any)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcolorbox` normally issues `\pagebreak` (among other things) when starting; this is ignored in `tabular`, but not in `longtable`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many,listings}
\usepackage{longtable}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.8\textwidth}|p{.2\textwidth}|}\hline
\begin{tcblisting}{
  nobeforeafter, % <--- added
  colback=bg,
  size=minimal,
  hbox,
  listing only,
  listing options={language=Mathematica}
}
f[x_] := Sin[x];
Plot[f[x],{x,-Pi,Pi}]
\end{tcblisting}
&
plot command
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]