# using \tcbinputlisting shows first page only when hbox is set

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I'd like to use the `hbox` option with `\tcbinputlisting` since it automatically adjust the background color and the box to the width of the code listing. The problem is that if the code listing is more than one page long, it only shows the first page (it can't break the hbox over multiple pages?)

I'd like to ask if someone knows a trick to allow one to use `hbox` and still show all the pages? Without `hbox` option, I lose the main advantage of using this package, and can just use the listing package directly.

Here is a MWE of the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}    
\usepackage{upquote} %to fix string quotes
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}
\tcbinputlisting{nobeforeafter,enhanced,listing only,hbox,
   breakable,listing file=HW2.m,size=small,
   listing options={framerule=0.05pt,style=Matlab-editor,numbers=left,
       numberstyle=\scriptsize,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,breaklines = true,
       escapechar=`,showspaces=false,mlshowsectionrules = true}}
\end{document}
```

output is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This problem also happens when using `\begin{tcblisting}..code..\end{tbclisting}` using same options.

You can use any file to see the problem, as long as the file is over a page long in code. If you like to use the above `HW2.m` file used in the example above, here it is [HW2.m](http://12000.org/tmp/062316/)

Again, the main reason I want to use hbox, is that it shrinks the background to the code size, which makes it look better. Here is reference  [how-to-crop-background-color-in-listings-to-the-longest-line-in-the-code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312111/how-to-crop-background-color-in-listings-to-the-longest-line-in-the-code/316203#316203)

Comment: Perhaps the `blend into=listings` is a way to get  of this trouble! Personally, I don't see any advantage of `hbox`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hbox don't break over page -- see the documentation. But you can store the box in an array and retrieve the width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{filecontents}{mylisting.txt}
blbub
blblb
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\newboxarray{mylisting}
\tcbinputlisting{nobeforeafter,enhanced,listing only,hbox,
                 listing file=mylisting.txt,
                 size=small,
                 store to box array=mylisting,
                 listing options={framerule=0.05pt,numbers=left,
                                  numberstyle=\scriptsize,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
                                  breaklines = true,showspaces=false}}

\boxarraygetwidth[mylisting]{\mylistingwidth}{1}

\tcbinputlisting{nobeforeafter,enhanced,listing only,
                 breakable,listing file=mylisting.txt,size=small,
                 width=\mylistingwidth,
                 listing options={framerule=0.05pt,numbers=left,
                                  numberstyle=\scriptsize,
                                  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
                                  breaklines = true,showspaces=false}}

\end{document}
```

[image]