# strange error using tcolorbox or other resources. box array

Tags: tcolorbox, resources

I am doing something that you might think is a little strange, but have good reason for it.  The code below is generated by lua function I wrote.

For some reason, it fails when I do this more than 4 times.

Same code compiles ok when code is generated 4 times. On the 5ht time, I get an error. Here is MWE (to make MWE small, I used `\def` to save the code into it, it seems to work, instead of copying everything again)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}% 
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}
{
\usepackage{luatex85}
}
{}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}    
\usepackage{upquote} %to fix string quotes
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document} 

%this code below is autogenerated
\def\tbl{
\begin{longtable}{p{0.7\textwidth}}
{\newboxarray{mylisting}
\tcbinputlisting{nobeforeafter,enhanced,listing only,hbox,
listing file={toLua.txt},
size=small,store to box array=mylisting,listing options={framerule=0.05pt,numbers=left,
numberstyle=\scriptsize,basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
breaklines = false,showspaces=false}}
\boxarraygetwidth[mylisting]{\mylistingwidth}{1}
\tcbinputlisting{nobeforeafter,enhanced,listing only,
width=\mylistingwidth,left skip=5pt,
breakable,listing file={toLua.txt},size=small,
listing options={framerule=0.01pt,style=Matlab-editor,numbers=left,
numberstyle=\scriptsize,basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize
,breaklines = false,escapechar=`,showspaces=false,mlshowsectionrules = true}}
}
\end{longtable}
}

%make 5 copies, it fail. 4 copies is ok.
\tbl     
\tbl     
\tbl     
\tbl     
%\tbl   % uncomment to see the error !
\end{document}
```

4 times, it compiles OK and generates this pdf

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I un comment the 5th copy, it does not compile, and gives error

```
Package tcolorbox Warning: box array 'mylisting' is allocated again by \newboxa
rray. Memory and registers are wasted on input line 40.

(./toLua.txt) (./toLua.txt
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--4
[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
)

Package tcolorbox Warning: box array 'mylisting' is allocated again by \newboxa
rray. Memory and registers are wasted on input line 41.

(./toLua.txt) (./toLua.txt
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--4
[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
)
! Misplaced \noalign.
\pagebreak ->\noalign 
                      {\ifnum `}=0\fi \@testopt {\LT@no@pgbk -}4
l.41 \tbl
          % uncomment to see the error
?
```

I see the warning about `box array 'mylisting' is allocated again by \newboxa
rray. Memory and registers are wasted on` but since this is automated code, generated, I use the same box array `mylisting` at each (hardcoded name), as I have no idea how to clear this thing before generating the same code. But it should not really have caused this? But I am not sure. May be clearing box array `mylisting` each time will fix this, but I do not know how to do this.

The file `toLua.txt` used above is this: (plain text file, contains small code listing)

```
clear all;
s   = tf('s');
sys = ( s+1 )/(s^2  + s  +  1);
[num,den]=tfdata(sys,'v');
%convert to state space
[A,B,C,D] = tf2ss(num,den)
```

Again, I think it is resource problem due to `Package tcolorbox Warning:` but I do not know how to fix this warning.

Reference for some of the code I used in the tcolorbox above, is thanks to the answer here [using-tcbinputlisting-shows-first-page-only-when-hbox-is-set](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316275/using-tcbinputlisting-shows-first-page-only-when-hbox-is-set)

## EDIT

In response to comments about the original document. If you really need a tabular then using `tabular` rather than `longtable` will work. However, I would personally not introduce these complexities just because you need e.g. several code blocks within each `\tbl`. I'd just use `minipage`s or similar, if I wasn't going to use sub-figures and so on. But it is your document, after all, and not mine!

Comment: Why are you putting it in a `longtable`? And why are you allocating the array thing repeatedly?

Comment: @cfr I am putting in long table for formatting. This is just an example. In actuall code, I have more cells in the table.  For the second part, I have to allocate the array thing, since the code listing changes each time. I found out if I use it once (at first), the next time it will use the wrong value for the new code. It uses the original value there. And since I do not know how to clear this thing, I reuse it. I am using code example from the link I have there.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the warning. It is to do with the fact that the fifth one would need to go on a new page and it is impossible to break here as there are no rows.

Comment: @cfr I am not following you. It is a new table. It can go anywhere it wants. Each code is one separate table with one row?

Comment: It is a long table so it is trying to break the content across the page. It is not a `tabular`.

Comment: @cfr why Latex does not start the table on new page then? Is a user supposed to tell Latex this? I thought Latex does these things automatically. But I can change long table to tabular if that is all what it is. Thanks.

Comment: You are misusing tabulars. LaTeX can handle this, but you need to use an appropriate environment. A `tabular` may work, but it isn't a tabular. What's wrong with a `minipage`? That's the obvious solution. Tabulars are for things with rows and columns. If it doesn't have rows and columns, it probably ain't a tabular.

Comment: Note that whatever is autogenerating your code is autogenerating it wrong!

Comment: @cfr as I said, I need tabular, since I have more cells. I only showed one cell to make the example small. I switched to tabular, and the error went away. I know about minipages and all of this. But has to use table. If you like to add this to your answer I would accept it, since you brought this to my attention. I am used to using longtable all the time, and that is why I used it. But tabular will also work here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the array once, globally, to avoid the warnings. That won't fix the error which is due to the unsuitability of `longtable` here. It is trying to find places to page break and it can't because of the kind of content.

The most straightforward solution is probably a `minipage`. For example

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
clear all;
s   = tf('s');
sys = ( s+1 )/(s^2  + s  +  1);
[num,den]=tfdata(sys,'v');
%convert to state space
[A,B,C,D] = tf2ss(num,den)
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}%
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}
{
\usepackage{luatex85}
}
{}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\usepackage{upquote} %to fix string quotes
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\newboxarray{mylisting}
\begin{document}

%this code below is autogenerated
\newcommand*\tbl{%
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
      \tcbinputlisting{nobeforeafter,enhanced,listing only,hbox,
        listing file={\jobname.txt},
        size=small,store to box array=mylisting,listing options={framerule=0.05pt,numbers=left,
          numberstyle=\scriptsize,basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
          breaklines = false,showspaces=false}}%
      \boxarraygetwidth[mylisting]{\mylistingwidth}{1}%
      \tcbinputlisting{nobeforeafter,enhanced,listing only,
        width=\mylistingwidth,left skip=5pt,
        breakable,listing file={\jobname.txt},size=small,
        listing options={framerule=0.01pt,style=Matlab-editor,numbers=left,
          numberstyle=\scriptsize,basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize
          ,breaklines = false,escapechar=`,showspaces=false,mlshowsectionrules = true}}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}\medskip}

%make 5 copies, it fail. 4 copies is ok.
\tbl
\tbl
\tbl
\tbl
\tbl   % uncomment to see the error !
\end{document}
```

[image: minipages]

Comment: Thanks. I switched to tabular as I said, thanks to your comment. That solved for me. minipages and subfigures and all that, will be too cumbersome to use, since I have many cells. tables makes it very easy to arrange things. I just did not know I have to tell Latex where to start a longtable. I thought Latex will move the long table to new page if it needed more space.

Comment: @Nasser If used for its intended purpose, the `longtable` will indeed be moved to the next page if necessary or broken over *n* pages or whatever. That's what the package is for. But it is not designed to cope with the kind of thing you are trying to put in it, I think is the problem.

Comment: LaTeX can do many things, but it does rely on you choosing the right tool for the job. Without knowing more, I can't say what I would use for your document. Based on the MWE a `minipage` seemed best. That may not be so for the real document. I doubt `tabular` is an ideal choice, though it is unlikely to be a terrible one.

Answer (score 1):

A cure for the would be to issue a `\clearpage` every now and then between your `\tbl`.

**Suggestions**

- In a repeating code, you usually don't want to create new items, like `\newcounter`, `\newlength`, or as in your example `\newboxarray`. Do this outside the command, and before it.
- Be careful with `\def`. It doesn't check if the command already exists. Use `\newcommand` or `\NewDocumentCommand` unless you know what you are doing.

**Full Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}% 
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}
{
\usepackage{luatex85}
}
{}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}    
\usepackage{upquote} %to fix string quotes
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\begin{filecontents*}{toLua.txt}
clear all;
s   = tf('s');
sys = ( s+1 )/(s^2  + s  +  1);
[num,den]=tfdata(sys,'v');
%convert to state space
[A,B,C,D] = tf2ss(num,den)
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document} 
\newboxarray{mylisting}
%this code below is autogenerated
\def\tbl{
\begin{longtable}{p{0.7\textwidth}}
{
\tcbinputlisting{nobeforeafter,enhanced,listing only,hbox,
listing file={toLua.txt},
size=small,store to box array=mylisting,listing options={framerule=0.05pt,numbers=left,
numberstyle=\scriptsize,basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
breaklines = false,showspaces=false}}
\boxarraygetwidth[mylisting]{\mylistingwidth}{1}
\tcbinputlisting{nobeforeafter,enhanced,listing only,
width=\mylistingwidth,left skip=5pt,
breakable,listing file={toLua.txt},size=small,
listing options={framerule=0.01pt,style=Matlab-editor,numbers=left,
numberstyle=\scriptsize,basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize
,breaklines = false,escapechar=`,showspaces=false,mlshowsectionrules = true}}
}
\end{longtable}
}

%make 5 copies, it fail. 4 copies is ok.
\tbl     
\tbl     
\tbl
\clearpage      
\tbl    
\tbl   % uncomment to see the error !
\end{document}
```